# Androidx RenderScript not run android api<19

Tags: renderscript

I have use androidx with blur image, but when run android api< 19 crash app.
When i run with android>19, i run normal,not crash app and if i use android normal with "android.support.v8.renderscript" no crash app.
At build.gradle. I have add :

```
  renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Code app:

```
public static Bitmap blurBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,
                                float radius) {        //Create renderscript
    RenderScript
            rs = RenderScript.create(MyApplication.getInstance());

    //Create allocation from Bitmap
    Allocation allocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs,
            bitmap);
    Type t = allocation.getType();

    //Create allocation with the same type
    Allocation blurredAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs,
            t);

    //Create script
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8(rs));

    //Set blur radius (maximum 25.0)
    blurScript.setRadius(radius);
    //Set input for script
    blurScript.setInput(allocation);
    //Call script for output allocation
    blurScript.forEach(blurredAllocation);

    //Copy script result into bitmap
    blurredAllocation.copyTo(bitmap);

    //Destroy everything to free memory
    allocation.destroy();
    blurredAllocation.destroy();
    blurScript.destroy();
    t.destroy();
    rs.destroy();
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:
This issue is now fixed in the latest build tools. I've verified this by upgrading compile sdk to API 29 and build tools to 29.0.2.**

---

This has nothing to do with your implementation. It's a bug in the androidx library and in fact, it happens for me even on API 21 so it might have a bigger impact than you've experienced.

Someone has already filed issues [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119582492) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133169129). I've been following on the issue for quite sometime unfortunately there isn't much progress going on. This is currently a showstopper for me to migrate to AndroidX for many of my projects.

Comment: You can still migrate to AndroidX and then just use the non-androidX libraries. But, that being said - it has actually still caused me some issues on random devices :( so maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

The `Element.U8` argument for `ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create()` is not correct.

The `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` is expecting an `Allocation` with elements of type `Element.U8`, but a `Bitmap`-backed `Allocation` has elements of type `Element.RGBA_8888` (a.k.a `Element.U8_4`).

try:

```
ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs))
```

or in general:

```
ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, allocation.getElement())
```